# Converting to Greek numerals will not work as expected

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a program that I created that converts to Roman numerals, it works successfully. Now I'm trying to add in the idea of converting to Greek numerals with `argparse`, it will not go passed the first tuple: `("α", 1)` in the list. I'm using the same algorithm that I used to convert to Roman, but for some reason it won't work for my Greek? Why will this not work as I would expect it to?

```
# <~~ coding=utf-8 ~~>
import argparse


opts = argparse.ArgumentParser()
opts.add_argument("-g", "--greek", type=int,
                  help="Convert to Medieval Numerals")
opts.add_argument("-r", "--roman", type=int,
                  help="Convert to Roman Numerals")
args = opts.parse_args()


ROMAN_NUMERAL_TABLE = [
    ("~M", 1000000), ("~D", 500000), ("~C", 100000),
    ("~L", 50000), ("~X", 10000), ("~V", 5000),  # "~" indicates a Macron
    ("M", 1000), ("CM", 900), ("D", 500),
    ("CD", 400), ("C", 100),  ("XC", 90),
    ("L", 50),   ("XL", 40),  ("X", 10),
    ("IX", 9),   ("V", 5),    ("IV", 4),
    ("I", 1)
]


GREEK_NUMERAL_TABLE = [
    ("α", 1), ("β", 2), ("γ", 3),
    ("δ", 4), ("ε", 5), ("Ϝ", 6),
    ("ζ", 7), ("η", 8), ("θ", 9),
    ("ι", 10), ("κ", 20), ("λ", 30),
    ("μ", 40), ("ν", 50), ("ξ", 60),
    ("ο", 70), ("π", 80), ("ϙ", 90),
    ("ρ", 100), ("σ", 200), ("τ", 300),
    ("υ", 400), ("φ", 500), ("χ", 600),
    ("ψ", 700), ("ω", 800), ("ϡ͵", 900),
    ("α", 1000), ("β", 2000), ("γ", 3000),
    ("δ", 4000), ("ε", 5000), ("ϛ", 6000),
    ("ζ", 7000), ("η", 8000), ("θ", 9000)  # The Greeks weren't very creative
]


def convert_init(number, convert_to=None):
    display_numerals = []

    for numeral, value in convert_to:
        count = number // value
        number -= count * value
        display_numerals.append(numeral * count)

    return ''.join(display_numerals)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    if args.greek:
        data = convert_init(int(args.greek), convert_to=GREEK_NUMERAL_TABLE)
        with open("greek_numerals.txt", "a+") as file_data:
            file_data.write(data)

    elif args.roman:
        data = convert_init(int(args.roman), convert_to=ROMAN_NUMERAL_TABLE)
        with open("roman_numerals.txt", "a+") as file_data:
            file_data.write(data)

    else:
        raise NotImplementedError("{} is not implemented yet".format(args))
```

Output for Roman numerals:

```
124542
~C~X~XMMMMDXLII  # Works
```

Output for Greek numerals:

```
124542
ααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααααα # Only outputs the 1
...
```

Comment: It looks like the problem might be that the greek list is in ascending order, whereas your roman list is descending.

Comment: For the Greek, in the first iteration, count = number // value, the result will be the actual number, as the first value is 1. Then the number becomes zero. So if you put them in descending order it should work.

Comment: Also, you should stop the for loop if the number becomes 0

Comment: @NonlinearFruit I can't believe that makes such a big difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Greek list is in ascending order while the Roman is in descending order.

That causes to the first number processed in Greek, to be `1`, so it print `n` times the letter `α`, instead of decreasing larger numbers first.

So, just sort the list descending when you iterate it:

```
for numeral, value in convert_to: # Becomes:
for numeral, value in sorted(convert_to)[::-1]:
```